# How to Parse XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I have managed to read in a saved .csv file on my hard disc and get the data to poputlate a data table. I now want to take that data and put it into XML format, then send the XML to a web service. How can I do this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What have you already tried? What version of the framework are you using?

Comment: So, are you trying to write XML or read XML?

Comment: I should have said I am using Visual studio to do this and using framework 4. I am not really sure how to get the data into xml format. I researched it and think LINQ is the way to do it but not entirely sure?

Comment: @Evan Mulawski - I am trying to get the csv data into xml format ready to be sent to a webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XLinq is excellent for putting the data into XML.  If you can use an up to date .NET framework I highly recommend it.

There's some info to get started with here (for example)
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/xLinkDoc06202007130827PM/xLinkDoc.aspx

As for sending that XML to a web service, perhaps you should be calling the web service via a client automatically generated using the Visual Studio ServiceReference tool.

You may or may not need to send XML to that -- in many cases services are object-based (i.e. you'd not need XLinq, provided you can parse the CSV into the correct objects.)

/EDIT:

Rough example for calling webservices using WCF:

```
using(var client = new ServiceReference1.ThirdPartyServiceClient())
{
    client.SendSomething("123", "hello");
    string output = client.GetSomething();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in terms of what I have in place already - I have used the service reference tool before, I have created a web reference to the webservice that is already in place and have created a client app to consume the service. I am dealing with a company that has sent me files in realtion to the service like the endpoint, .wsdl and .xsd files. I will be getting their data in the form of csv. So I was uder the impression I would have to parse the data into and xml template then send it using the soap. What do you think the best way of doing this would be? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does their csv data come from the web service?  You should not have to use SOAP directly if you're using a WCF client (from ServiceReference).  But what you have to put in the request depends on their implementation.  Many webservice calls are like GetObjects(ObjectQuery query), AddObject(Object object)

Comment: No unfortuantely the csv file is coming from a third party, needs to be converted into xml, sent to the web service and all I have to worry about is getting a response from the web service e.g. the file has been accepted or and error message. I have an example xml send file but not entirely sure how I would use this in my client app to send?

Comment: Without knowing the schema for the web service you're calling, I don't think I would be able to help much further.  You may not be at liberty to post the schema here, but if you can, it would help.

Comment: In terms of your feedback it has been very much appreciated. I can't post the schema publicly unfortunately. However you have been a great help so thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to connect to the Web Service using WCF (or ASP.NET Web Services depending on which .NET version you're using). You can then easily fill the proxy classes the framework creates for you and call the service.

The second option would be to use an [`XmlTextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx) and use that to build the XML document in a `MemoryStream`. Once you have the XML document built in memory, you can flush the document and send it out to the Web Service.

A third option would be to use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to build the XML document on the fly. Depending on the structure you parse your CSV file into this may be easier/harder for you than using the XmlTextWriter.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using XLinq over XmlTextWriter, it is much simpler syntatically.

Answer (score 1):

Following code can also be used.

```
public static List<Student> convertXMLtoList(string filePath)
{
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
List<Student> studentsMarks = doc.Descendants("Student").Select(x => new Student()
{
RollNo = int.Parse(x.Element("roll_no").Value),
Name = x.Element("name").Value,
}).ToList();
return studentsMarks;
}
```

Where XML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Students>
  <Student>
  <roll_no>1</roll_no>
  <name>XYZ</name>
 </Student>
...
</Students>
```

You can find more details at [http://bit.ly/1eveLz3](http://blog.kushdilip.com/2014/01/converting-csv-to-xml-and-then-to-c.html). you can find CSV to XML also on this post.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this with a datatable, but it work great for other objects.

Try something like this:

```
       public void writeToXML(DataTable inputData, string fileName) {
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataTable));
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName);
        xml.Serialize(sw, inputData);
        sw.Close();
   }
```

Edit:  Just noticed you needed to pass it along to a web service.  So instead of StreamWriter, use a memory stream...but same idea.

Answer (score -1):

There are different options depending on how robust of a solution you want.  Assuming you want to follow the quickest route you should look at the [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28VS.71%29.aspx). Using an XmlWriter you can quickly generate an XML document, save to string and then pass along to your web service.